# MinIO server does not work on VirtualBox shared folder

Tags: debian, minio

Minio Server starts in any folder apart from shared folder. I want to start the server in shared folder.

VirtualBox - Guest - Kali Linux
Host  - Windows 10

Command to start the minio server:

```
$ minio server s3bucket --console-address ":9001"
```

In any directory other than shared folder--

```
Formatting 1st pool, 1 set(s), 1 drives per set.
WARNING: Host local has more than 0 drives of set. A host failure will result in data becoming unavailable.
WARNING: Detected default credentials 'minioadmin:minioadmin', we recommend that you change these values with 'MINIO_ROOT_USER' and 'MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD' environment variables
MinIO Object Storage Server
Copyright: 2015-2023 MinIO, Inc.
License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
Version: RELEASE.2023-05-04T21-44-30Z (go1.20.3 linux/amd64)

Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline. 
S3-API: http://10.0.2.15:9000  http://172.17.0.1:9000  http://172.18.0.1:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000     
RootUser: minioadmin 
RootPass: minioadmin
```

In shared folder --

Just blank, nothing moving.